# What is the purpose of the KML XMLNS in a KML's source?

Tags: kml

I am looking over some KML documents source code and have noticed a difference in some of them.

Some have:

> kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">

and others:

> kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">

I was would like to know the purpose of this string (as a complete novice), does it have any implication to how a KML is generated / operates?

Comment: A common reference to the KML standard - so everyone developing tools/web browsers are reading the same standard. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language#OGC_standard_process

Comment: Thank you. So it is a bit like a reference at the end of a chapter or book, and has no real impact on the display / content of a kml file?

Comment: Google Earth Pro  uses it to determine which way to handle the file. Older version has less functionality. (1.2 vs 2.2)